# Is it possible to center the scrollbar of a div with overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css, web-applications, telerik

```
.qsf-demo-canvas 
{ max-width: 100%;
max-height:600px;
overflow:scroll;}
```

Is it possible to center the horizontal scrollbar with an overflow:scroll div.

If the content was much wider than the available space the div content would be centred by default?

The user should still be able to scroll though.

thankyou

Comment: it should still be scrollable by the user ? i ask because in title you have `hidden`in css you write `auto` and in text you write `scroll`

Comment: sorry my bad ... too much coffee!!!

Comment: It would be overflow:auto - or scroll I suppose

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: sorry - ive updated the question now.

Comment: I think that this question shouldn't be tagged as "rad". I would radther add "web-application" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS it's possible :
this scrolls the internal scroll of a div to it's horizontal middle

```
var myDiv = $("#Mydiv");
var scrollto = myDiv.offset().left + (myDiv.width() / 2);
myDiv.animate({ scrollLeft:  scrollto});
```

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: This puts the left side of the content at the center.  I think what the poster wants is to put the center at the center.

Comment: That the right idea, just needs a little more math to get it centered

Answer (score 1):

I had success with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var myDiv = jQuery("#myDiv"),
        myChild = myDiv.find("> *:first-child");
    myDiv.animate({
      scrollLeft: (myChild.width() - myDiv.width()) / 2
    }, {
      duration: 0
    });
  });

  jQuery(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: It works well when the scroll is relative to a child, such as an image inside a div (and that image is larger). Combining with other answers, the scrollLeft value can be `let scrollto = (img1.width() - div1.width()) / 2;`

Answer (score 1):

Some optimization - change animate to `scrollLeft()`. Works with jQuery.slim and according to Chrome DevTools, is much faster.

```
var myDiv = $("#Mydiv");
var scrollto = myDiv.offset().left + (myDiv.width() / 2);
myDiv.scrollLeft(scrollto);
```